# This perl syntax is confusing

Tags: perl

Perl Inline::C package has the following example,

```
use Inline C => config => inc => '-I/inc/path';
```

Wonder if the part

```
C => config => inc => '-I/inc/path'
```

is equivalent to

```
C => {config => {inc => "-I/inc/path"}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the revised notation compile? Does it work?

Comment: I know perl doesn't like `use Inline C => {config => {inc => "-I/inc/path"}}`.  Just try to understand what the syntax `C => config => inc => '-I/inc/path';` means here. Never saw this syntax else where other Inline::C module.  Would appreciate some explanation or pointer to document on the syntax.

Comment: That's not equiv.  But this is:  "`use Inline qw{ C config inc -I/inc/path }`", or this:  "`use Inline 'C', 'config', 'inc', '-I/inc/path';`"  or this: "`use Inline C => ( config => inc => '-I/inc/path' );`"

Comment: In other words, everything after "Inline" is just a flat list.

Comment: Maybe this is even clearer: `use Inline C => ( config => ( inc => '-I/inc/path' ) );` (That syntax represents the semantic meaning best)

Comment: Internally the Inline module is being told to use the C ILSM, which is provided by Inline::C.  Next the config => flags are processed, first by Inline::C, and then whatever Inline::C doesn't deal with gets passed up the chain to Inline.  So you're not actually using "Inline::C" explicitly; you're using Inline, and it knows to use the Inline::C extension to provide the C ILSM.

Comment: See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) -- the `=>` is basically just a comma with the added feature that it pretends the part on the left is quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the same. The `=>` is a comma which auto-quotes the expression on its left. So your code is equivalent to:

```
use Inline 'C', 'config', 'inc', '-I/inc/path';
```